What is a Lattice trapdoor?
In "A New Approach for Non-Interactive Zero-Knowledge from
Learning with Errors" , Brent Waters uses lattice trapdoors to build hidden bit generators. Can someone explain to me what a lattice trapdoor is?

A trapdoor function is a general concept in cryptography that (informally) is a function that is easy to compute going one way, but difficult to go in the other direction without knowledge of some secret.
In this case, the LWE problem is a (lattice) trapdoor. I have not read this paper, but by the sounds of it this may be what the author is referring to.

I mean, you explained the concept of a trapdoor function, which is not what I asked. After reading another paper, I think I understand it now: a lattice trapdoor is a short basis of the lattice that makes it easy to solve hard problems on it when you own it.

I see what you meant by your question now, I thought it was asking what the trapdoor function itself was, not the secret that makes computation easy. In that case, these notes by Ducas do a very good job at explaining how and why it is that a sufficiently good basis does this.
